# How do I change the chart title font size in a loop using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create some VBA code that runs through every sheet, making the chart title `font size = 18`, chart axes `font size  = 16`, the `chart width = 6`, and `chart height = 12`. Currently having a hard time with the font size inside a loop

> Getting error: Object doesnt support this property or method

```
     Sub ResizeCharts()   'Make all charts on active sheet uniform size.  

       Dim cht As ChartObject 

       For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        cht.Height = Application.InchesToPoints(6)
        cht.Width = Application.InchesToPoints(12)
        With cht.ActiveChart
             With .ChartTitle
                 .Size = 18
             End With
         End With  
       Next 

     End Sub
```

Comment: What line gives that error?  Is your `for each` actually on the same line as the dimension?  Given this has ">" indicating lines, I don't want to make any assumptions.

Comment: The for each is as it appears above. The line "With cht.ActiveChart" gives the error

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to do `With cht`?  Since `cht` is a `ChartObject`...

Comment: can you elaborate? Im a rookie

Comment: @BruceWayne is just telling you to try remove the `.ActiveChart` part from the line that throws the error and just keep `With cht` instead, as you are already looping through `ChartObject`s so you can't find an `.ActiveChart` (you're already manipulating the chart itself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @BruceWayne says, you want to use the `cht` object and also loop through your worksheets (if you want to do all the charts in all of the sheets)

```
For Each Sht In Application.Worksheets
    For Each cht In Sht.ChartObjects
        cht.Height = Application.InchesToPoints(6)
        cht.Width = Application.InchesToPoints(12)
        cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 18
    next cht
Next Sht 
End Sub
```